# How to implement PropertyChanged in order to refresh my Datagrid after my ComboxSelection has changed

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I have a datagrid and a combobox.  I can't seem to get my datagrid to refresh on selectionchanged of my combobox. I'm getting the value (_mySelectedValue) but my datagrid never loads. I tried aDataGrid.refresh.

The grid should load when I select the Combobox.Name, which gives me the ID in _mySelectedID, which my query then uses to query the database and refill my collection. (I think..)

ViewModel

```
  public class UserViewModel : ViewModelBase, IUserViewModel
{
    public DataEntities _context = new DataEntities();
    public ObservableCollection<UserChoice> userChoices { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CompanyName> companyNames { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<UserTable> userTables { get; set; }

    public UserViewModel()
    {
        GetID();
        GetDataAsync();
   }

    public async Task GetDataAsync()
    {

        var serv = (from s in _context.UserChoices
            join sa in _context.CompanyNames on s.CompanyID equals sa.CompanyID
            where sa.CompanyID == mySelectedItem  //crap left this out
            select s).ToList();
        userChoices = new ObservableCollection<UserChoice>(serv);
    }

    public async Task GetID()
    {
       var data = _context.CompanyNames.OrderBy(o => o.CompanyID).ToList();
       CompanyNames = new ObservableCollection<CompanyName>(data);
   }

    public byte _mySelectedItem;
    public Byte MySelectedItem
    {
        get { return _mySelectedItem; }
        set
        {

            _mySelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
        }
    }
  }
```

XAML

```
 <Grid Margin="0,0,-200,0">



    <DataGrid x:Name="aDataGrid" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding userChoices, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" 
              EnableRowVirtualization="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="159" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="337" 
              Margin="156,57,0,0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="actChoice" Width="*" Header="Choice" 
                                Binding="{Binding Choice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="actDescription" Width="*" Header="Description" 
                                Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Grid x:Name="grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Company Name:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="companyNameComboBox" Grid.Column="1" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName"  
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding companyNames}" 
                  Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" 
                  SelectedValuePath="CompanyID" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path= MySelectedItem, Mode= TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  SelectedIndex="2">
           <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: I can't see _mySelectedID anywhere in your code, so i don't understand how you think that your query is being used for it, and your query is only run once by the looks of it. Also, you're binding to user choices which doesn't notify when changed. Is this all of your code?

Comment: SO sorry. I copied in the code where I was testing.. where sa.CompanyID == mySelectedItem  //crap left this out  I fixed it above. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `GetDataAsync()` inside your setter for `MySelectedItem`, and then make `userChoices` raise a property changed event.

Also, you aren't `await`ing any calls in your async methods, so you shouldn't make them async.

```
public void GetData()
{
    // Also remember to plug in the correct company ID!
    // I removed the join, too, because it looks like you don't need it.
    // If you actual query is more complicated then feel free to add it back.
    var serv = (from s in _context.UserChoices
        where s.CompanyID == MySelectedItem
        select s).ToList();
    userChoices = new ObservableCollection<UserChoice>(serv);
}

public void GetID()
{
   var data = _context.CompanyNames.OrderBy(o => o.CompanyID).ToList();
   CompanyNames = new ObservableCollection<CompanyName>(data);
}

private ObservableCollection<UserChoice> _userChoices;
public ObservableCollection<UserChoice> userChoices 
{
    get { return _userChoices; }
    set
    {
        _userChoices= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("userChoices ");
    }
}

private byte _mySelectedItem;
public Byte MySelectedItem
{
    get { return _mySelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _mySelectedItem = value;
        GetData();
        OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
    }
}
```

**Edit**

To make a save method (based on your comment) I would use an `ICommand` since you have a view model. If you do this, you will first need to install the `Prism.Mvvm` NuGet package to get the `DelegateCommand` class (in the `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands` namespace).

Then add this code to your view model:

```
public void Save()
{
    var context = new AADataEntities();

    // Make changes to the context here...

    context.SaveChanges();
}

private ICommand _saveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save);

public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get { return _saveCommand; }
}
```

Now wire up the save command in the xaml like this:

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! In that case, you should mark this as the answer.

Comment: Hey AJ how would you add a "Save" method? Lets say I change the information in the datagrid. Would It be something like this?

Comment: this did not workprivate void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AADataEntities context = new AADataEntities();
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: Thanks again. Would a add new record be about the same? I was able to get the update working. Your examples have helped me learn a tremendous amount. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem! Yes, you would use a similar technique to add a record (or make any button click command, really). You can also assign commands to other events, such as key presses. See the [Commanding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want more info on commands.

Comment: AJ can you take a look at my other question? I'm trying to remove the View from my Shell region in Prism.

Answer (score 0):

Independent of code incoherence pointed by @Jevans92, I can see one problem, which is the SelectedValuePath + SelectedValue combination on Combobox.

You see, it only looks up for the selected value and updates it visual, but it never updates de binded SelectedValue back. So, if you have a pre-set SelectedValue and load the UserControl, then the Combobox looks up for the correct value to show, but if you change selection, it does not update the SelectedValue object bound to the control.

**Long story short:** Try removing both SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue and using SelectedItem instead.

If you have to deal only with selecting from the UI to the VM, then you don't event need to call PropertyChanged, as it is only used to notify the UI about changes on the VM.

But, if you need to also set the SelectedItem on the VM for the UI to show, then you will have to implement it.

Also note that, if you are dealing with different instances on your ItemsSource and your SelectedItem, you'd better override Equals + GetHashCode on that class, else it will never be looked up on your SelectedItem.

Comment: Hey Gabriel and thanks for pointing that out. I did try to remove both SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue, but I must not have my SelectedItem binded correct because it did not work. My Combobox is displaying Names of companies and I am wanting the ID of those names sent back to my ViewModel, so I can run the query again. It seemed to me that with your suggestion I'd only receive back the Names of my companies and not the ID. Also yes to this "But, if you need to also set the SelectedItem on the VM for the UI to show, then you will have to implement it."

Comment: Oh yeah. Forgot to say: For it to work, SelectedItem must be a property of the same type as the items of the list bound to ItemsSource. I'll try an make a code sample rewriting your VM and View.